# Git: Complete sync (not merge) with remote repo

Tags: git, repository, reset

I don't want to just fetch changes from the remote repo and merge them into my local copy. I want to make my local copy identical to the remote repo. How can I do this?

I've messed up my repo somehow, but I know the remote repo is in solid shape. I have no work completed since my last push, so I don't care if I lose anything.

Comment: Maybe a simple fresh `git clone` can do the job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st: fetch the remote changes:

```
git fetch origin # or whatever your remote is called
```

2nd: Reset your branches to the state the remote is at:

```
git reset --hard origin/master # or whatever the branch and remote is called
```

This will set the pointer to the head commit of the remote branch and throw away all your changes. Repeat the second step for every branch you want to reset.

---

In case you created some files that you never commited:

```
git clean -ndx # check which files will be removed
git clean -fdx # actually remove them
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting ``git clean -n`` first : ) People really shouldn't suggest ``git clean`` without letting others know the ramifications.

Comment: @NickTomlin Since I once destroyed my /etc with etckeeper and `git clean` I am super careful with that command ;)

Answer (score 2):

To make your local mirror the remote: 
`git reset --hard origin/master` 
(this assumes you have used `git fetch` to get the most recent reference to origin/master)

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard && git clean -dfx`

Comment: If `origin/master` is ahead of `master` this won't sync the two, it will just revert the working directory to the last commit of `master`. You'll still need to pull/fetch and merge.

Comment: @MattHarrison true, I guess it's just my muscle memory talking, when I "mess up" local repo I instantly run `reset && clean`, when I mess up real bad I just do `move foo bar && rd /s/q bar` and `git clone foo` in separate tab as no git command would give me full OCD-level satisfaction of truly identical repo.